# Set Env Variables and Run Shell Script From Python Script

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm pretty new to Python and trying to find an approach for setting up several shell env variables and then executing a shell script.

Is the `subprocess` module capable of sending several shell commands and capturing the output?

This isn't clear to me, since each spawn will result in a new shell thread that will not have the previous env variable.

Also, would it be appropriate to use `popen` or `check_output`?

Essentially what I'd like to do is:

```
$ setenv a b
$ setenv c d
$ setenv e f
$ check_status.sh > log.log
$ grep "pattern" log.log
```

Where `check_status.sh` must have the above env variables defined to run properly, and it also must be shell script (i.e. I can't translate `check_status.sh` to python).

I'd appreciate you comments and input.

Comment: @favoretti haven't tried, just thinking of an approach. Also not looking for a code solution, just your thought on the problem statement.

Comment: @favoretti although ["Interacting with Another Command"](http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/) section seems interesting.

Comment: Have you seen this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971312/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-python? Note that it says that child processes auto-inherit set values, so short answer is yes, it's possible. :)

Comment: And here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964515/calling-a-subprocess-in-python-with-environmental-variables is a code example. Ignore the `su` part, you don't need it, his problem is that `su` resets the environment.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess` will create one thread everytime. You can use `popen` to execute shell command. Use semicolons as separators. Such as `os.popen('setenv a b;set env c d')`

Hope it helps.